# What domestic glue to put back a phone's LCD?

Tags: repair, cell-phone

I have a new LCD for my HTC phone, but unfortunately it's not press-fit or screw on like some older phones. I have to re-glue it back. What domestic glues (not superglue as I've heard it cracks when dry) could I use to put my LCD screen back onto my phone please? I was thinking a more glutenous glue like vinyl repair or heated glue? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacement screens, event rebuilds, may come with an adhesive strip already attached. This is also how these screens were mounted in the first place.

If that is not the case we may use double-sided adhesive tape (AKA double-sided sticky tape, mounting tape, carpet tape) that we cut into the desired dimensions.

Before we attach the replacement we have to carfully remove **all** remnants of the original tape.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Who are the 'we' though? :P

Comment: @Fandango68: "we" is you and me, our friends, and of course our families :D

Comment: Agreeing on double sided adhesive tape. Just that for some phones, you'll need a transparent version (e.g. made by 3M … buy a small sheet via eBay and cut one stripe off for each edge).

Answer (score 1):

If you're mounting a screen assembly (protective glass/touch sensitive digitiser/LCD display) onto a phone chassis, a double sided sticky foam as Takkat recommends - surprised it didn't come with the display/wasn't already attached but may be available separately, computer cut for your exact phone dimensions

If you mean glueing a protective glass onto a digitiser or digitiser onto an LCD (depending how your phone screen stack is constructed) there's a specific glue for it, referred to as LOCA, optically clear (and indeed forms a vital part of the vibrancy of the display) - it is set using UV light after being applied

Both these items are available on the likes of amazon and eBay. Your local mobile phone repair place should also be able to advise and supply